# Auto Capitalize Dynamic list in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating an excel sheet to manage all equipment in my workplace using serial numbers.

For the sake of preventing duplicate data entry I've used "Data Validation" & "Dynamic List" through excel.

Using the Formula:

```
=COUNTIF(SerialNumber,E2)<=1
```

Where SerialNumber is a column of the excel table created, so it refers to:

```
Inventory[Serial Number]
```

I'm trying now to use the same Dynamic list to force capitalization of all serial numbers entered, I've seen solutions using VBA, however I've got no clue how to use the same Dynamic list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use another defined Name (ctrl+F3) without VBA.
You will get another dynamic list to use.
For Capitalization, you can use proper() or upper() function.

```
CapSerialNumber=PROPER(Inventory[@[Serial Number]])
```